# Does the youtube iframe embed cause errors for just Edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, youtube-iframe-api

Just using the following embed seems to throw errors for Edge on mac, while Firefox, Chrome and Safari work just fine. Am I missing something, or is this the same for everyone?

The snippet copied from youtube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9aAkFJj4H4I" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Errors in Edge:
[image: remote.js:34 GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED]

`remote.js:34 GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED` comes from https://www.youtube.com/s/player/5253ac4d/player_ias.vflset/en_US/remote.js

Working example: https://codepen.io/roelvanhintum/live/KKVxwLq

Comment: The error is probably caused by Chrome Cast being absent in Edge. See if you can force-enable it via `chrome://flags`, see if it was reported to Edge developers already, or report it yourself otherwise.

Comment: If your company is using the proxy or the VPN then this kind of error may occur. I found a similar kind of thread in which the user had an issue with the Chrome browser. You can try to contact your IT department. They may help you to fix this issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425009/why-am-i-getting-this-error-chrome-extension-invalid

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT unfortunately it's the same on different connections, even at home.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I don't know what to look for. I've never used chrome cast myself.

Comment: I try to do some further research on this error message and it looks like it is a network-related error. You can notice that Video is playing fine in the Iframe. It looks like if that extension is not under our control then we can't stop that error. see the answer in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514297/get-neterr-failed-error-when-probing-for-extension