# chrome-extension://invalid net::ERR_Failed only in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, chromecast

**Website works completely fine**, until you inspect element and put it in mobile mode:

[image]

Then this error pops up:

[image]

here is a snip it of my code:

```
<script async src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         "use strict";
var Context;
    window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function (isAvailable) {
        if (isAvailable) {
              Context = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance();

                Context.setOptions({ receiverApplicationId: "<HASH>", androidReceiverCompatible: true, autoJoinPolicy: "ORIGIN_SCOPED"});

                Context.start;
     }
  }
</script>
```

website is using a SSL cert

Comment: 1) are you developing a website or a chrome extension? 2) is 'invalid/' your intended path? does that path exist? 3. Are you sure that error emitted from your shown code snippet?

Comment: 1) a website 2) the invalid path comes from the google cast_sender.js (in the snip it) 3. yes  the error comes from cast_sender.js

Comment: the error occurs on this line: "(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(c)" in the cast_sender.js

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425009/why-am-i-getting-this-error-chrome-extension-invalid

Comment: Thanks, seen that but didn't solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This took me way to long to work out, but here it is:

[image]

If you select an apple product it comes up with the error, but not with the android devices.